# Can I create a half-circle with rounded corners?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, workflow

I am trying to create this shape in Illustrator and finding it particularly difficult:

[image]

Creating a circle and cutting it into thirds isn't that difficult but rounding the corners similarly on each side is a bit more tedious - I can't think of how to round the corners another way than making a complex cookie cutter shape and using Pathfinder.

**Can this shape be created simply and quickly in Illustrator?**

Comment: Select the corners with the white arrow tool and drag the round corner widget?

Comment: @joojaa this is not an option once you clip a circle into a half circle

Comment: It definitely is. You might just have two overlapping points or your settings cap rounding widget visibility for angles this thight. In either case it does work. Try just setting the value of round in the top horizontal toolbar.

Comment: @joojaa the rounded corners handles are not a great solution (or good UX), since they disappear as soon as I adjust the height or width of the half-circle

Comment: Sure but then illustrator is not the tool you should be using. It just simply does not have a enough indirect modelling tools to handle even most rudimentary cases. Simply illustrator is a direct modeling tool it can not make you build parametric objects reliably (Direct modelling means redoing work for small changes.). Illustrator can slo never be this tool as it would mean everything in illustrator would need to change ground up. Including changing all its users.

Comment: If you change your shape with either the Transform Panel or you Scale it- it will keep the rounded corners although their proportions will change if you make non proportionate (in height and width) changes to your shape. If you just click a line segment and drag it then yes, the round corners will go away (rather they will get messed up). I am not sure why you would expect a different behavior.

Comment: @Kyle i think you should just publish your answer.

Comment: @MicroMachine I think theres much to be said about having a indirect modelling tool that would have as much pront view options as illsutartor but cirrently no such thing exits

Comment: @joojaa I just wish there was a non-destructive way of doing things, the way - I don't know - InDesign handles corners in a non-destructive way... Or a simple way to make symmetrical shapes by only designing one side and having the other side be mirrored automatically...

Comment: @Kyle But thats the answer. Illustrator will not become a tool that can simply do this. Adobe had the option to do this whan they released CS1 they just didnt press the advantage of the live vector styles so iot would be a full on node network. And adobe is occupied with other things since then. A shame but reality

Comment: @MicroMachine Its a tradeof, if the corner widgets are locked i get other problems namely that i need to start expanding things when i do other things. Its just easier for the average user is what you see is what is there. Essentially adobe was doing whatyou wanted, but decided to move the other way and chose the easier solution. Which probabbly is better for adobe customers but not for the long term ecosystem. Simply a choice has to be made do you want a kickass direct modeller or a good indirect modeller. Theres really little middle ground

Comment: @MicroMachine You can make ilustrator make the object auto symmetric though. Just not round the corners, since the round effect is broken (adobe has had 10 years to fix this they havent so they will never do it)

Comment: @joojaa I agree with most all you said, except I do not think at all that Adobe made Illustrator "simple". It is probably the most illogical Adobe app from a UX standpoint and getting the simplest things done can take hours for nothing...

Comment: @MicroMachine no ist fast its just that you do not have experience in working with ruler and pen. So essentially its hard if you over think it None of your questions actually takes more than 2 minutes to draw. Its just that your ont equipped to draw directly

Comment: @joojaa You mean a physical ruler / pen or the illustrator features? What I mean by the user experience is horrible by 2022 standards has to do with selecting anchor points or handles being a nightmare (no snapping?), not being able to modify shapes without losing editable corners (InDesign does it), double-clicking a gradient swatch opens the color picker instead of the Gradient Panel, the Layers panel can go outside the bottom of the screen, having to re-check "Preview" in Panels every single time, clicking a Swatch in the Swatch Panel sometimes adds a stroke, cannot move diagonally...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135730/discussion-between-joojaa-and-micromachine).

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible there is something off in your construction of the cut circle shape ? Corner widgets will work (must use white arrow tool to select the points). Make sure View> Show/Hide Corner Widgets is ticked on. This works for a circle cut with a rectangle by pathfinder> minus front (shown) and also for a circle cut with scissor tool and then joined to form a closed shape.

[image]